# Android studio, firebase data retrieving

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-listview

I have tried to fetch data from firebase realtime database,  but i get ana error `"Anonymous new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() can be replaced with lambda"`, please help me to write the code below with lambda format.

here is the code.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,answer.class);
                        String p=answer_list.get(position);
                        intent.putExtra("answer",p);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite your code using lambda expressions, it will be as simple as:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, answer.class);
    String p = answer_list.get(position);
    intent.putExtra("answer", p);
    startActivity(intent);
});
```

Meaning that you provide an implementation of the `onItemClick` method in a Java 8 style.